# set horizontalGap and with on a single button inside a buttonbar

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have the following togglebuttonbar:

```
<mx:ToggleButtonBar buttonWidth="85" height="45" id="menuBar" width="595" x="0" y="23">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.CONNECTION_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/Bonjour.png')" label="   "/>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.LANGUAGES_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/languages.png')" label="   "/>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.TAGGING_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/tag.png')" label="   "/>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.FONT_MAPPING_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/FontPanel.png')" label="   "/>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.ERROR_CHECKING_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/Clear-Green-Button.png')" label="   "/>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.USERS_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/UserAccounts.png')" label="   "/>
            <mx:Object data="{LocalConfig.UPLOAD_STATE}" icon="@Embed(source='resources/images/Network.png')" label="   "/>
        </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:ToggleButtonBar>
```

What i would like is that the last button has a 10 pixel horizontalGap so it stands apart from the rest of the buttons. I would also like for it to be a bit smaller than the other buttons. Is it possible to do it or should i try a different approach? I also tried to just define it as a seperate button but then you loose the effect of a pushed in button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a different style for the last element in a toggle button bar by using:

```
lastButtonStyleName
```

Using this you can style it however you like.

If you need to go more in depth you can extend the ToggleButtonBar class and make your overrides there as needed.  :)